# d3.js updating x domain doesn't move the graph

Tags: d3.js

I am building a d3.js chart [here](https://observablehq.com/@lieuzhenghong/solar-power-interactive-visualisation) that updates on input. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

And here is the code:

```js
chart = {
  var data_filter = (data.filter(d => d['date'].toISOString().split('T')[0] == viewof date_picker.value));
  
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

  
  const x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data_filter, d => d.dt2))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
  
  const xAxis = function(g) {
      g.attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))
  }
  
  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data_filter, d => d['system_demand_actual'])]).nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
  
  const yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text(area_needed.y))
  
    
  const line = function(property) {
    return d3.line()
      .defined(d => !isNaN(d[property]))
      .x(d => x(d.dt2))
      .y(d => y(d[property]))
  }

  svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .call(yAxis);

  const path_demand = svg.append("path")
    .datum(data_filter)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("d", line("system_demand_actual"));
  
 const path_supply = svg.append("path")
    .datum(data_filter)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("d", line("total_supply"));
  
  function update() {
    data_filter = (data.filter(d => d['date'].toISOString().split('T')[0] == viewof date_picker.value))
    data_filter.map((d) => d['total_supply'] = d['PVOUT_AVG'] * viewof area_multi.value);
    
    x.domain(d3.extent(data_filter, d => d.dt2));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data_filter, d => d['system_demand_actual']) * 2]).nice()
    
    path_demand.attr("d",line("system_demand_actual"));
    path_supply.attr("d",line("total_supply"));
  }
  
  update();  

  viewof area_multi.addEventListener("input", update);
  viewof date_picker.addEventListener("input", update);

  return svg.node();
}
```

The update function works for the area_multi (moving it increases the height of the red line), but when I change the date in the date_picker, the graph doesn't seem to redraw, even though I change the x.domain in my update function:

[image]

Comment: Which Browser/OS are you using? Changing the date updates the graph for me. (Chrome/Windows 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `datum` on the paths as well.

In the `update` function:

```
-    path_demand.attr("d",line("system_demand_actual"));
+    path_demand.datum(data_filter).attr("d",line("system_demand_actual"));

-    path_supply.attr("d",line("total_supply"));
+    path_supply.datum(data_filter).attr("d",line("total_supply"));
```